# Matching anything in between two characters even if characters are embedded internally

Tags: java, regex

Sorry about the confusing title, but I'm not sure how to word this. Also, I am very inexperienced with regular expressions. Here's my problem:

I am extracting text that is in between the delimiters "{{" and "}}". I need this to match over multiple lines as well. This is easy with the regex expresssion:

**pageText = pageText.replaceAll( "(?s)\\{\\{.*?\\}\\}", "" )**

However, I'm running into the issue that additional delimiters are embedded within the block of text like so:

**"some text here {{ should {{ all be }} removed }} and some more text"**

When I use the regex above on that string I get:

**some text here  removed }} and some more text**

when it should result in:

**"some text here and some more text"**

So I need to extract everything in between {{ .. }} ignoring if it contains another {{ .. }} within it.

I've been reading a lot of questions on here and Google, but I couldn't find anything tackling this specific problem. I'm particularly interested if there is a way to do this with regular expressions. It seems I can write some function that performs this task (although I'm struggling with that as well as the logic is not very simple), but I would like to have it done within a few lines without exposing myself to any errors coming from the code that I write.

Any help or direction is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Java does not allow recursive regular expressions, sorry!

Comment: Java regexes can't deal with an undetermined number of nested brackets because Java regexes don't have tools like recursion or a stack system as in .net. You must write your own parser or use a third library.

Comment: Thanks for the input Evan & Casimir, I have since settled on writing my own parser and have gotten it to work. However, Indu's answer below seems to also be working for as many nested delimiters as I throw at it (I just tried to throw 12 nested delimiters at it and it still worked). I'm probably missing something, but it seems to contradict what your comments have stated. I've already posed the question to Indu, but I'm wondering about your thoughts on the issue: without Java regex being able to handle the nested brackets, why is his answer working? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried just this "\{{2}.*\}{2}"?

```
pageText = pageText.replaceAll( "\\{{2}.*\\}{2}", "" )
```

I tested this on your sample, and it worked.
I tested on this as well:
"some text here {{ #@#$%%^^ {{ should {{ all be }} removed }} $%^&* }}and some more text"
and it worked as well.

Just try it out and let me know.

Comment: This seems to be working very well! Thanks for your input. I've accepted your answer for now, but may I ask why does this work? What does the '{2}' mean in this regex? I ask because I first thought it meant ignore up to 2 {{ }} nested patterns in the String but it seems to work for all nested {{ }} patterns. I've tested it with 4 nested delimiters and it worked. I also ask because of the comments to my original post said I can't do this without writing my own parser (which I ended up doing anyways). Thanks again!

Comment: `\\{{2}.*\\}{2}` is same as `"\\{\\{.*\\}\\}"`

Comment: Appreciate the help Indu!